# Xdebug doesn't get enabled in docker container

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, xdebug

I'm using [richovery/nginx-php-fpm](https://github.com/richarvey/nginx-php-fpm). Everything works fine but I've faced with a problem on enabling the xdebug. As I read the documentation the xdebug is installed by default in the container and only thing to enabling it is adding **ENABLE_XDEBUG= 1** environment variable to **docker-compose.yml** file so I tried it but no result! So I decided to enable it manually in my Dockerfile by running the command **docker-php-ext-enable xdebug**. While compiling I see some execution results in terminal which are associated with this job however when I dump the **phpinfo()** I can't see anything related to the xdebug. Also the **docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini** does not exists in the **/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/** directory. And the funny part is when I go into the container and run the command **docker-php-ext-enable xdebug** and restart the **php-fpm** it works like a charm.

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
     admin_panel_web:
     build: ./nginx
     ports:
       - 81:80
     volumes:
       - ../src:/var/www
     working_dir: /var/www
   admin_panel_mysql:
      build: ./mysql
      ports:
       - 3307:3306
      restart: always
      environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin_panel
      MYSQL_USER: tohid
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123456
      volumes:
       - ../data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
       - ./mysql/conf:/etc/mysql/conf.d
   admin_panel_redis:
      build: ./redis
      ports:
       - 6380:6379
   volumes:
       - ../data/redis:/data
```

And my Dockerfile

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.8.2
#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
# Configure nginx
#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#-#
ADD conf/nginx-site.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.conf
ADD conf/nginx-site-ssl.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
ADD conf/xdebug.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```